# Weird crash with generic UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm experiencing a weird crash (*see bottom of this post for the stack trace*) with a generic `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.

This is the root class for collection view cells in my project:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell<T> : UICollectionViewCell {

    private var _model : T?

    var model : T? {
        get {
            return _model
        }
        set {
            _model = newValue
            self.update()
        }
    }

    class func heightForModel(model : T) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func update() {

    }
}
```

Pretty basic.

This is the subclass that is causing the fuss.

```
class AnotherCollectionViewCell : CollectionViewCell<MyModel>

    // MARK: Update

    override func update() {

        /* Update the cell content... */

        self.contentView.setNeedsLayout() /* Crash occurs after the layout process has been triggered! */


    }

}
```

`AnotherCollectionViewCell` is being instantiated via a XIB.

If `AnotherCollectionViewCell` is a direct subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` there won't be any kind of crash!

**CRASH**

**iOS SDK**: 9.1

The error I get is:

```
-[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray
```

The stack trace is:

[image: Stack Trace]

It looks like a bug, as the code runs perfectly fine on the Simulator.

Any idea what could be causing the crash?

**UPDATE I**

I performed swizzling on UIView to check `_accumulateViewConstraintsIntoArray`.

[image: Swizzling]

This is the crazy result, just before the crash!

```
2015-10-29 11:23:16.660 Veni[625:990686] [-[UIView(Hack) swz_accumulateViewConstraintsIntoArray:]] TYPE: __NSArrayM
2015-10-29 11:23:16.661 Veni[625:990686] *** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray
```

**UPDATE II**

Dropping the generic makes the crash go away - but it's not "Swifty" anymore.

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    private var _model : AnyObject?

    var model : AnyObject? {
        get {
            return _model
        }
        set {
            _model = newValue
            self.update()
        }
    }

    class func heightForModel(model : AnyObject) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func update() {

    }
}
```

Comment: The stack dump doesn't include the method you say is causing the crash.

Comment: @JeremyP `setNeedsLayout` invokes all that stuff you see in the stack trace

Comment: Yes but not synchronously. setNeedsLayout sets a flag and then in a subsequent call to the runloop the layout change occurs. It's probably that you haven't set an outlet in the nib

Comment: @JeremyP I've double checked everything - this crash only occurs when using a generic Swift subclass. If the cell inherits directly from `UICollectionViewCell`, there won't be a crash. Also, it just works on the simulator.

Comment: If you use your swizzle method to call the original one with a -copy on the argument, does it work?

Comment: @Andrea It crashes with another error: `-[__NSArray0 addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector`

Comment: @MatteoPacini NSArray doesn't implement adObjectsFromArray: so this is correct... I really don't understand, it seems there is another layer of implementation is the argument passed to addObjectsFromArray: that must be an NSArray and is not. Seems really a bug.

Comment: @Andrea I've filed a bug report - will keep you guys posted.  I've dropped the generic (see last update in the post) as a temporary workaround.

Comment: In the generic version, what if you make T be constrained to a subclass of `AnyObject`?